# I have created a Handsontable and want to render Json Data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, handsontable

I have created a handsontable and getting a ajax request from local json file
and when i tried to render both rows are showing same values,

> [object, object]
>   currently getting json response in this way a array of two objects.

when i render on Handsontable getting like this
example:

```
name | phone ... 
test | 123123
test | 123123
```

I'm new to Javascript any help would be aapriciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON data :

```
var data.result = [ 
   {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
   {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
   {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
   ];
```

Get this data in jQuery:

```
$.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
    alert(data.result[i].PageName);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will integrate and check on it.